# How to quit "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to quit "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter" when deinit is called.

**subView.swift**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    self.doSomething()
}

func doSomething(){ 
    if self.subView.flgA == false { //error because subView's deinit is already called
        //...
    }
}
```

When ViewController do `_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` and deinit is called, deinit in ViewController and subView is called at first and after a few minutes `doSomething()` is called.
I want to stop `doSomething()` when popViewController is executed.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swift we have something called ARC([Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)).
ARC will make sure any object with at least one strong reference to it, will not be removed from memory.

In your case you're creating a strong reference to `self` in the closure of the async task created by `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`.

You need to tell the compiler that this reference is either `weak` or `unowned`(See attached link for more info.), this will enable the instance of `self` to be deinitialised even though you have a reference to `self` from the closure.

The `weak` keyword can be used in cases where you want the closure to run and make actions that doesn't require a reference to `self`. This is helpful to use if you don't know if `self` is alive or not.

The `unowned` keyword can be used in cases where you don't need the closure to run without a reference to `self`. This must be used in cases where you know self `self` is still alive.

Getting a `weak` or `unowned` reference of self in the closure can be achieved like in the example below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    [weak self] in
    self?.doSomething()
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    [unowned self] in
    self.doSomething()
}
```

It's worth mentioning that if you're not using a deadline, but calling `.async { ... }` directly does not result in capturing self and therefore can be used safely without defining `weak/unowned self`.

Answer (score 15):

You could schedule a `Timer` with this code block

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] timer in
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

hold on to the timer and cancel it before `popViewController` like this:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Notice the `[weak self]` and the `self?.domeSomething()` which I put there to avoid the hard reference to the viewcontroller and read Laffen's more detailed answer on this.

Comment: I didn't know that I can write it like your code that uses Timer and [weak self]. Thank you!